# Background Image is not shown

Tags: html, css

in my Vue Application I have a login page, where I want to show a specific background. I tried to set the background like this:

```
`<template>
  <div class="background"></div>
</template>

<style>
  .background {
    background: url("./images/background.svg");
    background-size: cover;      
}
</style>`
```

Now when I open the browser and watch the inspector, it says that the width and heigt of the div is 0x0. The html and body elements are also set to height 100% and width 100%.

When I define a specific height and width in the css the picture is shown, but I want to make the background responsive so this is no option for me. Does anyone know what the issue could be?

Comment: You have to nail down the height and width. You can make it responsive with CSS media queries.

Comment: i have watched many tutorial about this topic and no one used fix heigths and width. some people used vh for example but no one used media querys. Is there no other way to do that?

Comment: the div as a block level element has a default height as auto that when the element has no content it translates to zero. So the quickest solution is just to set its `height: 100vh;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you insert the below properties it should tell the .background to fill the viewport, this may mess up the aspect ratio. But depending on your needs this can be fixed, the second set of code will prevent the img from showing up more than once and will tell it to keep the original proportions.

Hope this helps

```
height: 100vh;
width: 100vw;

background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-attachment

Comment: You could also use an Auto width to keep the image from stretching as well

Comment: this solution works pretty good for me, thank you :)